# Rails - Strong Parameters - Nested Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I've got a pretty simple question. But haven't found a solution so far.

So here's the JSON string I send to the server:

```
{
  "name" : "abc",
  "groundtruth" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 2.4, 6 ]
  }
}
```

Using the new permit method, I've got:

```
params.require(:measurement).permit(:name, :groundtruth)
```

This throws no errors, but the created database entry contains `null` instead of the groundtruth value.

If I just set:

```
params.require(:measurement).permit!
```

Everything get's saved as expected, but of course, this kills the security provided by strong parameters.

I've found solutions, how to permit arrays, but not a single example using nested objects. This must be possible somehow, since it should be a pretty common use case. So, how does it work?

Comment: have a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483963/rails-4-0-strong-parameters-nested-attributes-with-a-key-that-points-to-a-hash

Comment: @vinodadhikary It was correct… I think the OP is confused. As odd as it sound when you want to permit nested attributes you do specify the attributes of nested object within array. On the other hand if you want nested of multiple objects then you wrap it inside a hash… see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit and https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L246-L247

Answer (score 203, accepted):

As odd as it sound when you want to permit nested attributes you do specify the attributes of nested object within an array. In your case it would be

**Update** as suggested by @RafaelOliveira

```
params.require(:measurement)
      .permit(:name, :groundtruth => [:type, :coordinates => []])
```

On the other hand if you want nested of multiple objects then you wrap it inside a hash… like this

```
params.require(:foo).permit(:bar, {:baz => [:x, :y]})
```

Rails actually have pretty good documentation on this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit

For further clarification, you could look at the implementation of `permit` and `strong_parameters` itself: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L246-L247

Comment: both cases are the same in this answer, actually, it's just that the curly brackets are optional around { :groundtruth => [...]}; It's a hash but the interpreter is able to determine where the hash begins and ends without explicit curly brackets.

Comment: Nested arrays of attributes do not allow nested attributes. Nested attributes and attr_accessor are listed in my application as "Unpermitted parameters". Still looking for safe solution.

Comment: In case of multiple nested objects, you should also permit the id for this to work. More info here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308714/nested-fields-and-strong-parameters

Comment: This only permits ONE set of nested attributes. This will not work in the case of a one to many.

Comment: @speakingcode if that's the case I suspect it's better practice to keep the curly brackets so the reader of the code has a clearer understanding of what's going on

Answer (score 26):

I found this suggestion useful in my case:

```
  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name).tap do |whitelisted|
      whitelisted[:data] = params[:product][:data]
    end
  end
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454#issuecomment-14167664) of Xavier's comment on github.

This approach whitelists the entire params[:measurement][:groundtruth] object.

Using the original questions attributes:

```
  def product_params
    params.require(:measurement).permit(:name, :groundtruth).tap do |whitelisted|
      whitelisted[:groundtruth] = params[:measurement][:groundtruth]
    end
  end
```

Comment: Just a side note, This will still show in the log as unpermitted parameters but the model will accept them anyways.

Comment: Not sure of Rails 4 but in my Rails 5 project I have to call `permit!` to be whitelisted or else it's remained unpermitted after tapping it. In this case it would be `params[:measurement][:groundtruth].permit!`

Comment: @nayiaw i also get the unpermitted message but adding `permit!` raises this error `NoMethodError (undefined method `permit!' for #<Array:0x007f80cb71ea00>):`

Comment: @wuliwong `permit!` method is not available in `Array`. You'll need to have access to the respective class instance to have access to `permit!` (it's been a while so I've forgotten the class name but it's something like `ActionController::Parameters` based on [this page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit)).

Answer (score 13):

Permitting a nested object :

```
params.permit( {:school => [:id , :name]}, 
               {:student => [:id, 
                            :name, 
                            :address, 
                            :city]},
                {:records => [:marks, :subject]})
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is Rails 5, because of new hash notation:
`params.permit(:name, groundtruth: [:type, coordinates:[]])` will work fine.