# Problems saving my nested form using the params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, nested-forms

I am trying to make a nested form that can be edited then saved. Whenever I go to save the form though I get the error:

> Couldn't find ClassInstance with ID=11 for Collection with ID=

11 is the ClassInstance id for the first ClassInstance in the form, and it appears that the Collection id is being set to NULL.

I have tried to manually set hidden ids in the controller `form_for` as well as setting a hidden field in _class_instance_fields.html.erb for the :collection_id.

What is ActiveRecord trying to do and why is it getting confused? Am I doing something you aren't supposed to with nested forms?

I have included some of my code with the fluff removed so that it isn't as much to look through.

collections_controller.rb

```
 def update
    @collection = Collection.new(params[:collection])

    if @collection.save
      flash[:notice] = "IT WORKED"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "No Cigar...."
    end
    redirect_to collection_path
  end

  def read
      @collection = Collection.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
      @classes = Classification.all 
  end
```

read.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @collection, url: {:action => "update", collection_id: @collection.id} do  |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :id #I had hoped this would fix it%>
        <table class="instance_table">
                <%= f.fields_for :class_instances do |builder| %>
                    <%= render 'shared/class_instance_fields', :f => builder, :status => '0' %>
                <% end %>
                <tr><td>
                    <%= link_to_add_fields "Add an Instance", f, :class_instances  %>
                </td></tr>
        </table>
        <%= f.submit "Save"%>
    <% end %>
```

_class_instance_fields.html.erb

```
<tr class="record_row">
    <td>
        <%=  f.label( :name) %></p>
    </td>
        <%= f.hidden_field :status, :value => status  %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :collection_id %>
    <td>
        <% if status == '1'  %>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to f.object.name, instance_edit_path(f.object.id) %>
        <% end %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <% if status == '1' %>
            <%=  f.select :classification, options_for_select(@classes.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]},selected:  f.object.class_id)%>
        <% else %>
            <%= f.label :classification,  displayClassInstanceName(@classes.select{|a|  a[:id] == f.object.class_id }[0])  %>
        <% end %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <% user = nil%>
        <% id = nil %>
        <% if status == '1' %>
            <%collection = current_user.id %>
        <% else %>
            <%collection = f.object.collection_id %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.label :username, displayUserName( user ) %>

    </td>
    <td>
        <%= removeRecordLink(f) %>
    </td>

</tr>
```

### Additional Info

I have been using `Rails.logger.debug` to inspect the params before I save them. With the folling code in the `update

```
Rails.logger.debug "TG: " << params.to_yaml
```

I get the following output

```
TG: --- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
utf8: ✓
_method: put
authenticity_token: efvqGsLKJfdCsadfjsad9fsD97dfgYaOUjsg+uvAQi2+k4=
collection: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  name: mikee's Collection
  class_instances_attributes: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    '0': !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
      status: '0'
      collection_id: '8'
      _destroy: '0'
      instance_attributes_attributes: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
        '0': !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
          id: '1'
          _destroy: '0'
      id: '11'
commit: Save
controller: collections
action: update
id: '8'
```

Maybe that can help make sense of things, as I am not too experience with params and I'm not sure what I should be seeing there for nested forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to the others, I do not believe this is a strong parameters issue. Strong parameters only kicks in when you say something like `params.require(:collection)`.

I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do here. Your method is called update, which indicates that it updates an existing record, but instead it creates a new one (`Collection.new`). I will assume you are trying to update an existing record.

There are a few problem-areas here. First, the controller. Replace this:

```
@collection = Collection.new(params[:collection])
```

with this:

```
@collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
@collection.assign_attributes(params[:collection])
```

Then the view...

When a form updates a resource in Rails, the standard procedure is to include the object ID in the form action URL. That happens automatically when you use `form_for @collection`. Since you are overriding the form's url with `url: {:action => "update", collection_id: @collection.id}`, it is not generating the path correctly. Change your `form_for` line to:

```
<%= form_for @collection do |f| %>
```

and remove `f.hidden_field :id`

For this to work correctly, you must have the appropriate route set up in `routes.rb`. I'm assuming you have a line in there like `resources :collections`.

I can't tell what you're trying to do with class_instances, but if you're hoping for additional objects to be created when you save your collection, you may  need to set `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on your Collection model. Read about that here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Once this is working, you may want to replace `params[:collection]` with `collection_params`, and then you should add a method to your controller

```
protected
def collection_params
  params.require(:collection).permit(:param_1, :param_2, :param_3)
end
```

Where :param_1, :param_2, :param_3 are the params you wish to allow the user to update.

See https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters and [Rails 4 - Strong Parameters - Nested Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436741/rails-4-strong-parameters-nested-objects)

Comment: Thanks for the help in understanding what I was messing up with my form. That had actually been bugging me for a while! I thought it was really weird that I was using new to update the Models and I kicked myself when I realized that I was looking at the wrong action in the example when I made my controller.

Comment: Yes I did, trying to use new was foolish, using assign_attributes fixed me up right! It was frustrating and relieving to find out that I missed such a tiny detail :P Thanks again! On to the next problem :P

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment on your post but don't have 50 reputation yet... so I'll just post here. Hope you'll find it helpful.

Have you tried `<%= @collection.inspect %>` before your form to see what data Rails is dropping into the form? You shouldn't have to specify the `id` or `collection_id` anywhere, since `form_for` takes care of that for you.

I would comment out the rest of the fields in your form and then do a `render text: params.inspect and return` in your `update` action to see exactly what data is being sent to it via PATCH (assuming you're running Rails 4).

If the `id` (or `collection_id` depending on your route) shows up properly, then you can start uncommenting parts of the form... rinse and repeat until you find the offending code.

Edit: I agree with Philip7899. This appears to be a strong parameter issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already been doing something similar. I have been using `Rails.logger.debug` to check what the form is passing to the controller. I feel like I've done a lot of rinsing and lathering with the fields I supply. I'm going to update my question with the results of the output that I get though, maybe that could shed some light, as I'm not too sure what it is supposed to look like

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 4, add :id to your strong params for class_instances.  If you're using rails 3, make the changes to your model so that the user can set them.