# accepts_nested_attributes with HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, has-and-belongs-to-many

```
class OptionValue
    has_and_belongs_to_many :listings, join_table: 'listing_options'
    belongs_to :type

class Listing
    has_and_belongs_to_many :option_values, join_table: 'listing_options'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :option_values
```

I've looked at several questions here on the same topic, however in all those questions the asker wants additional functionality on the relationship and goes with the :through instead. I am looking to add values to the join table using the accepts_nested_attributes.

A listing has an option value for each option type. After processing the params received from the form they look like this:

```
listing_params => { "option_values_attributes"=> [{"option_value"=>"3"}, {"option_value"=>"5"}, {"option_value"=>"9"}]}
```

Calling Listing.new(listing_params) in create gives the error message

```
Unpermitted parameters: option_values
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: option_value
```

Other attributes are successfully saved to the new listing instance. I've also tried option_value_id as parameter with the same result, and including @listing.option_values.build in new doesn't make a difference. I could convert the relationship to a :through relationship, but I do not need that type of relationship and would expect the HABTM to be more efficient otherwise. Is there something else I'm missing in the parameters, or should I change the relationship type to :through?

edit - relevant controller code

```
def create
  *binding.pry*
  @listing = Spree::Listing.new(listing_params)
  # @listing.save
def new
  @listing = Listing.new
  @listing.option_values.build

def listing_params
  params[:listing][:option_values_attributes] = []
  ovs = params[:listing][:option_values].values
  ovs.each do |ov|
    params[:listing][:option_values_attributes] << {"option_value" => ov}
  end
  params.require(:listing).permit(permitted_listing_attributes)
end

def permitted_listing_attributes
  [ :listing_options_attributes => [[:option_value_id]]] ]
end
```

edit - I now believe adding to the join table via accepts_nested_attributes is not supported in rails. Passing the option value ids as such raises an error. When instantiating a new listing (below), **passing the type_id does not raise an error**, indicating that we could use the accepts_nested_attributes with HABTM to create new option values, but not for adding only to the join table.

```
Listing.new({state: "1", "option_values_attributes" => [{"type_id" =>"30"}] })
```

Comment: Could you post your controller information, more specifically where you whitelist the strong parameters (`listing_params`)?

Comment: The params given above are what's returned from calling listing_params. Here is the relevant permitted attributes: def permitted_listing_attributes
  [
  :listing_options_attributes => [[:option_value_id]]]
  ]
end

Comment: It looks like you aren't utilizing strong parameters properly. I'll update my answer with more information.

Comment: Do you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :option_values` in your `listing` model? seems like you don't have it.

Comment: @Pavan - yes, updated that in the question.

Comment: @jkeuhlen - I've looked at the docs, will check out the railscast you linked to.

Comment: Your controller code would be very useful.Can you post it?

Comment: @bjorn You aren't using strong parameters correctly. Take a look at [this other SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436741/rails-4-strong-parameters-nested-objects) if the railscast doesn't help.

Comment: @jkeuhlen - could you be more specific on what's not right with the strong parameters? I had looked through the documentation & many SO questions to get the parameters working and they are returning the correct results. I've just done some more testing on them and only scalar values matching the option_value key pass the params. If anything I may need to have the parameters in a different format to be accepted as attributes for the listing model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, take a look at the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) for accepts_nested_attributes.

You need to include the parameters for `OptionValue` you are wanting to update in the params for `Listing`.

Another resource other than the docs: an excellent [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).

Your notion that HABTM is "more efficient" than a has_many :through is false. In fact, if you dig into the way rails implements HABTM, you'll see that it just creates another has_many :through. An easy way to see this is to `reflect_on_all_associations()` for one of your classes. You won't see a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship but you will see an association for `has_many :through` a join table and a `has_many` for a relationship to the join table. If you know how to solve this problem using `:through` instead, just make the switch.

Comment: Pro tip:  never use HABTM relationships.  It is confusing for no good reason.  Has many through is better.

Comment: @ruby_newbie Agree except sometimes if all you need is really simple many to many with no nesting or anything else HABTM is faster.

Comment: Does seem rather confusing. So I've tried out the reflect_on_all_associations() on listings and don't see a through: relationship for the listing_options. Will likely switch over to through: tomorrow.  @macro=:has_and_belongs_to_many,    
@name=:option_values,
@options={:join_table=>:listing_options, :autosave=>true},
@plural_name="option_values",