# Losing parameters in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Or, that is what seems to be happening. I'm getting errors in my production environment that i can't recreate in development. Basically, i'm trying to associate a Booker to a Booking. If the Booker doesn't exist I'd like to invite him/her.

```
# GET /bookings/new
def new
  @booking = Booking.new
  authorize @booking

  @booking.venue = Venue.new
  @booker = User.new

end
```

Relevant create code;

```
def create

  @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
  authorize @booking

  booker_found = set_booker
```

And the set_booker private method

```
def set_booker

  logger.info "booker: #{booking_params.inspect}"

  # set existing user as booker or prepare inviting a new user
  booker_found = false
  @booker = User.find_by_email(booking_params[:user][:email])
```

etc. 
**The last line is where I get errors in production, because `booking_params[:user]` does not exist.** I tried resetting my database in the development ENV and the code works fine. Yet in production I will always get `NoMethodError (undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass)`

This is my relevant form code;

```
<%= simple_form_for(@booking, :wrapper => :bootstrap3 ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for @booker do |user_form| %>
    <%= user_form.input :email, label: "Booker e-mail" %>
  <% end %>
```

This is what logger shows in development;

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lala", "booking"=>{"name"=>"Mah Booking", "date"=>"02-10-2014", "venue_name"=>"Meeeeeeeeeeee", "venue_id"=>"", "user"=>{"email"=>"booker@boekkoek.nl"}, "artist_fee"=>"0.00"}, "commit"=>"Create Booking", "locale"=>"en"}

booker: {"date"=>"02-10-2014", "name"=>"Mah Booking", "artist_fee"=>"0.00", "venue_id"=>"", "venue_name"=>"Meeeeeeeeeeee", "user"=>{"email"=>"booker@boekkoek.nl"}}
```

And this is from my production.log

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yada", "booking"=>{"name"=>"tttt", "date"=>"02-10-2014", "venue_name"=>"meee", "venue_id"=>"", "user"=>{"email"=>"info@blabl.nl"}, "artist_fee"=>"0.00"}, "commit"=>"Create Booking", "locale"=>"en"}

booker: {"name"=>"tttt", "date"=>"02-10-2014", "artist_fee"=>"0.00", "venue_id"=>""}
```

I have no idea why the order is different, also, it seems to but "cutting off" after the venue_id, which is obviously causing the error. Has anyone seen behavior like this before?

**Edit:**
Here's my booking_params private method

```
def booking_params
  params.require(:booking).permit(*policy(@booking || Booking).permitted_attributes)
end
```

And the pundit policy;

```
def permitted_attributes
    [:status,
   :date,
   :name,
   :get_in_time_string,
   :soundcheck_time_string,
   :dinner_time_string,
   :show_time_string,
   :show_time_end_string,
   :artist_fee,
   :venue_id,
   :venue_name,
   :act_ids => [],
   user: [ :id, :email ]
    ]
end
```

Like I said, same code works fine in development. The only way I can sort of reproduce the problem is by removing the user params from my `permitted_attributes` method, but then I actually get an "unpermitted parameters" error. What would be the right way to define the permitted attributes for "user"? Totally lost on this one.

Comment: the `params` hash does have a `booking` key, containing a Hash which contains a key/value pair for the key `user`. Your strong parameters configuration must be incorrect and does not permit access to these params maybe? (like @Niall pointed out)

Comment: Are you using the same ruby version on the server as in development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never found out what the problem really was. Not using Pundit for the strong params fixed it though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your strong parameters are incorrect/are missing the nested `user`. If you post them I can fix that side of it, but an easy temporary fix is to simply use

```
params[:user][:email]
```

i.e access the parameters directly. Going back to the issue, have a look here for using nested parameters in the strong parameters:

[Rails 4 - Strong Parameters - Nested Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436741/rails-4-strong-parameters-nested-objects)

Comment: The principle of the strong params is to not use directly `params`. I agree this is a easy fix but it is wrong to do so