# Nested params with Strong Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

In a Rails 5.1 app, from my view, I send the following to my controller

> "area"=>{"name"=>"name", "project_id"=>"123",
>   "owners"=>{"step2"=>["345", "678"], "step3"=>["123"]}}

How can I, with Strong Parameters, allow the entire content of `owners` to get through?

I have tried what suggested in [Rails 4 - Strong Parameters - Nested Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436741/rails-4-strong-parameters-nested-objects) but nothing seems to work.

```
params.require(:area).permit(:name, :project_id, :owners)
params.require(:area).permit(:name, :project_id, owners: [])
params.require(:area).permit(:name, :project_id, owners: []).tap do |whitelisted|
 whitelisted[:owners] = params[:application_area][:owners]
end #=> ActionController::UnfilteredParameters - unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash:
```

The content of the `owners` hash may change from request to request; i.e. the next time I can send

> "area"=>{"name"=>"name", "project_id"=>"123",
>   "owners"=>{"color"=>["345", "678"], "shape"=>["123"]}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to white list all the possible values for owners

```
params.require(:area).permit(:name, :project_id, owners: [step2: [], color: [], step2: [], step3: []])
```

ok have you tried this for dynamic content with rails 5 ?

params.require(:area).permit(:name, :project_id, :owners => {})

Comment: I think you meant to list `:shape` instead of `:step2` twice.

Comment: Those values are dynamic, I mean they are defined as instances of another model. Therefore, I do not know all the possible value. Thanks

Comment: `params.require(:area).permit(:name, :project_id, :owners => {})` seems to be to teh reasonable option since `owners` is a hash and indeed it works. Thanks