# How to permit hash with rails strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I am working on a Model with an atter_accessor object named element. I want to pass the Array of form data to the element object. In Rails console I am getting Unpermitted parameter error.

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "category"=>{"name"=>"asfd", "body"=>"asf", "element"=>{"1"=>"asfd:text", "2"=>"asfd:text", "3"=>"asfd:text"}}, "type"=>"text", "commit"=>"Create Category"}
Unpermitted parameter: :element. Context: { controller: CategoriesController, action: create, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x0000000106b3ff68>, params: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "category"=>{"name"=>"asfd", "body"=>"asf", "element"=>{"1"=>"asfd:text", "2"=>"asfd:text", "3"=>"asfd:text"}}, "type"=>"text", "commit"=>"Create Category", "controller"=>"categories", "action"=>"create"} }
```

**In model** `attr_accessor :elements`

**In controller**

```
def category_params
  params.require(:category).permit(:name, :body, :elements => []) 
end
```

I tried with many alternatives changing the `:elements` to `element: []` too, nothing worked. I think I am missing something here which is the reason I am getting an unpermitted parameters.

Comment: I’m not sure with this, but you can try `params.permit(:name, :body, element: [])`

Comment: I tried, didn't worked. Am I going the wrong way!.

Comment: how about `params.permit(:name, :body, :element)` ?

Comment: I don't think this will work! It will return unpermitted parameters exception for all fields.

Comment: I’m sorry that I can’t help you with this, but I recommend you to change the `attr_accessor :element` to `attr_accessor :elements` so that your team work or other people who read your question will not misunderstanding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't mentioned the version of rails you are using but,
`:elements => []` does not work because elements is a ruby hash and not an array

**on rails 5.1+ you can use**

```rb
params.require(:category).permit(:name, :body, :elements => {})
```

Comment: Great, I was missing this. Thanks

Comment: This isn't quite correct. Nested parameters are actually instances of `ActionController::Parameters` and parameters whitelisting isn't some some case of an equity check.

Comment: @max I never claimed it was an equality check.  Just showing the OP how to fix their problem.

Comment: Is it possible to specify the permitted hash keys inside `elements`?

Comment: is it safe todo? since its accept whatever hash the elements have?

Comment: @max what do you mean by that max?

Comment: @Pioz yes it's possible to have nested objects in the strong params. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436741/rails-strong-parameters-nested-objects

Comment: @buncis generally speaking it's not a good idea, but it can depend on the application and the context. Sometimes when incoming json structure is dynamic there's  almost no choice but to allow all keys.  If possible you should avoid a blanket {}

Answer (score 0):

A lot of confusion going on here besides the `element` / `elements` naming issue - pick one and stick with it.

If you want to pass an array as FormData in Rack applications you need to use keys with empty brackets:

```
irb(main):001:0> str = "elements[]=a&elements[]=b&elements[]=c"                                                         => "elements[]=a&elements[]=b&elements[]=b"
irb(main):002:0> Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(str)                                                                   
=> {"elements"=>["a", "b", "c"]}
```

If you place any sort of value in the brackets it will be parsed as a hash instead:

```
irb(main):003:0> str = "elements[1]=a&elements[2]=b&elements[3]=c"
=> "elements[1]=a&elements[2]=b&elements[3]=b"
irb(main):004:0> Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(str)
=> {"elements"=>{"1"=>"a", "2"=>"b", "3"=>"c"}}
```

When whitelisting an empty array will permit an array of [permitted scalar values](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4.4/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html):

```
irb(main):005:0> params = ActionController::Parameters.new(Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query("elements[]=a&elements[]=b&elements[]=b"))
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"elements"=>["a", "b", "b"]} permitted: false>
irb(main):006:0> params.permit(elements: [])
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"elements"=>["a", "b", "b"]} permitted: true>
```

When whitelisting hashes you pass an array of symbols which represent the keys you want to permit:

```
irb(main):006:0> params = ActionController::Parameters.new(foo: { bar: 1, baz: 2, woo: 3 })
irb(main):007:0> params.permit(foo: [:bar, :baz])
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"foo"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"bar"=>1, "baz"=>2} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

You can also permit a hash with arbitrary keys by passing an empty hash:

```
irb(main):008:0> params.permit(foo: {})
=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"foo"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"bar"=>1, "baz"=>2, "woo"=>3} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

This is a somewhat dangerous operation and should be done with care.

Comment: it's kinda confusing, so in strong parameters the bracket doesn't mean the parameters comes in array/multiples, to make ruby/rails know that your parameters is array/multiple you need to add bracket with index into it more read [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions)