# Ruby on Rails/Devise - Creating organization and membership at the same time as signing up a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, devise, associations

I'm trying to build an app where when a user signs up, the user along with an organization and a membership to that organization are created. However, I continue to run into an issue where the user is created, but neither the organization nor the membership are.

I have tried many things, but mostly keep getting this same error:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :organization. Context: { controller: Users::RegistrationsController, action: create, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x0000000117db8248>, params: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Doe", "email"=>"john@test.com", "position"=>"CEO", "organization"=>{"name"=>"JohnDoeCo"}, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up", "controller"=>"users/registrations", "action"=>"create"} }
```

My models are as such:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_one :membership
  has_one :organization, through: :membership
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :membership, :organization

end
```

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, through: :memberships

    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My Registrations Controller is:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    super
    resource.build_membership
    resource.build_organization
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    super
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
    super
  end

  # PUT /resource
  def update
    super
  end

  # DELETE /resource
  def destroy
    super
  end

  protected
  
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(
        :first_name,
        :last_name,
        :position,
        :email,
        :password,
        :password_confirmation,
        organization_attributes: [:name],
        membership_attributes: [:organization_id, :user_id]
      )
    end
  end

end
```

And my view for registrations/new looks like:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "users/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :position %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :position %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :organization do |fm| %>

      <%= fm.label :name %><br />
      <%= fm.text_field :name %>

  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that `resource.build_organization` is running after the response is rendered and not before.

When `f.fields_for :organization` is then called `#organization` returns nil and not an instance of organization so Rails doesn't understand that it should be naming the parameters for nested attributes.

What you want to do is to pass a block to the super method:

```
# Do not use `::` when defining nested classes/modules
# @see https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition
module Users
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

    # GET /resource/sign_up
    def new
      super do |user|
        resource.build_membership
        resource.build_organization
      end
    end

    # ...
  end
end
```

This works since most of the [Devise controller methods](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/232c855c54cc3e471afbd48b6eda8ff164638c09/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L11) yield at key points to let you tap into the flow and do things to the resource:

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource
    yield resource if block_given? # <- your code should be running here
    respond_with resource
    # <- not here
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am still receiving the same error with this.

Answer (score -1):

The error is trying to tell you to whitelist the `organization` param. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18437539/1239774) and the [Strong Parameters documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

Comment: I changed the params based on your answer as follows to add the line:

`{membership_attributes: [:organization_id, :user_id, organization_attributes: [:name]]}`


But I am still running into the same error.

Comment: I don't have much experience in this, but from a scan of the docs, I think it might need to be `membership_attributes` when editing, and `membership` when creating

Comment: Just tried it without `_attributes` when creating, no luck.